# Executing maven tasks based on chosen profile

Tags: java, sql, maven, jdbc, pom.xml

I am currently developing my first JAX-RS based REST service and in order to access different databases based on the environment I am executing the service on, I added profiles to my `pom.xml`. Based on the currently chosen profile I am able to create a configuration file, that lets me establish the connection to the local database.

However, I also use this information to create a database and tables and load some test data into it using dbunit. The problem is, that the database is created and dropped for all profiles, but I just want to recreate the database for test profiles. If I use production or development profiles the database should just be altered if there have been structural changes to the database tables.

So my question is how I could execute plugin actions based on the currently chosen profile. Therefore please consider the example below. How to alter the executions so they are just executed if I set the profile `test` using `maven clean install -P test`?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${sql.maven.plugin.version}</version>

    <!-- Specify the dependent jdbc driver -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.jdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Common configuration shared by all executions -->
    <configuration>
        <driver>${database.jdbc.driverClass}</driver>
        <url>${database.jdbc.connectionURL}</url>
        <!-- You can comment out username/password configurations and have maven 
            to look them up in your settings.xml using ${settingsKey} -->
        <username>${database.jdbc.username}</username>
        <password>${database.jdbc.password}</password>
        <settingsKey>postgres-db</settingsKey>
        <!-- All executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true -->
        <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>drop-db-before-test-if-any</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- need another database to drop the targeted one -->
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432</url>
                <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                <sqlCommand>DROP DATABASE ${database.jdbc.dbName};</sqlCommand>
                <!-- ignore error when database is not available -->
                <onError>continue</onError>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>create-db</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432</url>
                <!-- no transaction -->
                <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                <sqlCommand>CREATE DATABASE ${database.jdbc.dbName};</sqlCommand>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>create-tables</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                <delimiterType>row</delimiterType>
                <srcFiles>
                    <srcFile>src/main/sql/spozz-schema.sql</srcFile>
                </srcFiles>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `plugin` is an [element allowed in a Profile](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-maven-profiles.html) put your plugin inside the profile, and declare the `executions` you want in the appropriate profile.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any mechanism to include profiles from external files? Otherwise my `pom.xml` will become too large.

Comment: @Avedo You can [include another pom](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html) we can say a composition approach, but i prefer an [inheritance approach](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-relationships.html#pom-relationships-sect-project-inheritance): define your profile in a parent pom extended by your maven project.